# How to use generic libraries from a Web framework?

Tags: apache, module, nginx, libraries, lighttpd

OK, I had a look at the memcached module for Nginx but this is clearly not for the faintheart.

Does anyone know about a way to load a library in memory and then use its functions - from a Web server like Nginx, Lighhtpd or Apache?

Example of such libraries abound like JSON parsers, Database client libraries, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to find anything about doing it but those guys have made it pretty easy:

http://dearetc.com/

It takes only one line of code to import a library and all its functions.

Hope it will help others...